# itterate through log file Powershell to grab line A and subsequent lines below until another line A

Tags: powershell, parsing, logfile

I have a log file with entries like

AA this is a line A

CODE C

CODE C

CODE C

AA this is a line A

CODE C

AA this is a line A

CODE C

CODE C

AA this is a line A

So I need to find the first

> AA this is a line A

and grab then all corresponding CODE C below and then ideally another object with AA this is a line A and the next CODE C until the whole file is done

I have:

```
$codelog = 'C:\data\code.log'


$collection = get-content $codelog

$endline = Get-Content $codelog | Measure-Object -Line | Select -ExpandProperty Lines
$i = 0
$withlines = get-content $codelog | foreach{"$i $_";$i++}
$linenumbers = @()

foreach($line in $withlines)
{
    if($line -like "AA This is a line*")
     {$linematch = $line.split(' ')[0];$linenumbers += $linematch} 
     
    
}

$totallines = $linenumbers | Measure-Object -Line | select -ExpandProperty lines

$linereader = @()
$linereader = 1
foreach($code in $linenumbers)
{
    
}
```

I can't get my head around

Comment: So you just want all lines starting from the first line `AA`? Or only the lines that are not starting with `AA` _after_ the first line starting with `AA`?

Comment: What kind of objects are you expecting? An array of arrays (lines) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the expected result should be. You talk about **objects**, but the example log and your code suggest you want an array of arrays (lines between the 'AA this is a line A' markers).

If that is the case, you can do this:

```
$codelog   = 'C:\data\code.log'
$collector = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$result = switch -Regex -File $codelog {
    '^AA this is a line A' {
        if ($collector.Count) {
            # output the array we already collected
            # the unary comma in front makes result to become an array of arrays
            ,$collector.ToArray()
            $collector.Clear()
        }
    }
    default {
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) { $collector.Add($_) }
    }
}

# process what you now have parsed out
$result | ForEach-Object {
    # each $_ is an array
}
```